# Insertar archivos (imagenes,videos,documetos,pdf,docs,excel,impress...) en una DB con php mysql con BLOB

Tags: sql

estoy intentando hacer un formulario que, inserte un archivo de imagen en la DB. Pero no me inserta nada, porque será?

HTML:

```
    <form method="POST" action="" id="form_chat_do" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table id="botones_chat_do">
        <tr><td><textarea placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje" name="mensaje_text"></textarea><input type="text" id="validar_chat"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>
            <div id="div_file">
                <i id="texto_archivo" class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>
                <input type="file" name="archivo" id="añadir_archivo">
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td><button id="enviar"><i class="fa fa-send"></i></button></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$conexion = new mysqli("","","","");
if (!$conexion) {
    die("Error al conectar con la DB: ".$conexion->connect_error);
}
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
$fecha = date("d/m/Y");
$hora = date("G:i");
$mensaje = $_POST['mensaje_text'];
// Este es el archivo temporal:
$tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
$nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
$tamaño = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
$imagen = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
$insertar = "INSERT INTO table1 (clase,nombre_archivo,tipo_archivo,tamaño_archivo,mensaje,fecha,hora) VALUES ('1A','".$nombre."','".$tipo."','".$tamaño."','".$mensaje."','".$fecha."','".$hora."')";
echo mysqli_query($conexion,$insertar);
$conexion->close();
?>
```

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`clase` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
`nombre_archivo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`tipo_archivo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`data_archivo` blob NOT NULL,
`tamaño_archivo` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`mensaje` varchar(11000) NOT NULL,
`fecha` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`hora` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

Gracias.

Comment: Hola. Con ese código no vas a guardar un fichero viable, para empezar en la parte de PHP, al crear la query no estás insertando el campo `data_archivo`. No vas a poder crear los registros en BD. Aparte, lo que deberías hacer es almacenar la imagen en el servidor y almacenar después la ruta en base de datos en lugar de esta.

Answer (score 0):

Como tal no puedes meter un archivo en la BD, es una mala práctica, sin embargo si realmente quieres ingresarlo puedes pasarlo a base 64 en PHP con `base64_encode()` lo que te permite ingresarlo como un String a tu BD, para volverlo a obtener sólo tienes que decodificar la imagen `base64_decode()`

Comment: porque es más recomendable subirlo al servidor y después guardar la URL en la base de datos, que no directamente en la base de datos? Que ventajas y desventajas tiene guardarlo directamente en la DB?